# getJSON IP + country code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have strange problem, I am trying to get country code (like US for United States) from IP, I need to use free APIs so I found ipify for IP (works well) and trying to use geoplugin for country code, here is my code:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json', function(r){

alert(r.ip);

$.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=' + r.ip + "jsoncallback=?", function(y) {

    alert(y.geoplugin_countryCode);

});
});
```

IP shows in alert, just like I wanted but there is problem with geoplugin JSON, it shows me error in browser: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` like it found error in that JSON and it's trying to run the code (changed my IP): https://gyazo.com/c96a9aa50ac1d886b37b95b583e1415e

Comment: JSONP is not JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here it is! The following code snippet successuffly logs the country code.**

So Replace your code with the following code snippet, I used AJAX to achieve your goal:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json',
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success : function(data) {
        alert( data.ip );
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?' + data.ip + '&jsoncallback=?',
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function(data) {
                alert( data.geoplugin_countryCode);
                //you can print variable: "data" as well, or any property as data.someProperty
            },
            error : function(error) {
                console.log("Could not get information: " + error);
            }
        });
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log("Could not get information: " + error);
    }
});
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @KrzysztofWurst you're welcome! you can upvote also :-)

Comment: I did but as a new account it doesn't show as upvote ;(

Comment: While this may solve the problem, an explanation on the "why" would increase the long-term value of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

update it like below

```
$.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json', function(r){
    $.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=' + r.ip, function(y){
        alert(y.geoplugin_countryCode);
    });
});
```

You can use it with another method. Add the script in your page

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(geoplugin_countryCode());
</script>
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, an explanation on the "why" would increase the long-term value of the answer.

Comment: Thank you mate, it also works but I am using first method :)